# Android onActivityResult not called / triggered

Tags: android

I read much about issues with `onActivityResult`, but it seems that none of the described problems fit to mine, like putting a negative requestCode in `startActivityForResult` or something else.

I'm playing with the camera in my Activity, which streams its preview to a SurfaceView.
After taking a picture, I close the cam releasing its resources, call `setResult(RESULT_OK, DataIntent)` and hoping that `onActivityResult` is triggered in my parent.

But it doesn't. If I set a result in `onCreate` of the child Activity and finish the child in onCreate the result is not passed to onActivityResult.

What possible reason could it be that `onActivityResult` is **not** getting triggered?
I'll write some of my source down for understanding of what I'm doing...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button mButtonScan;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mButtonScan = (Button)findViewById(R.id.main_btn_scan);
    }

    /**
    * OnClick Event called from main.xml
    * @param v View that called that onClickEvent
    */
    public void btnCaptureClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CaptureActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, Constants.REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE);
    }

    /**
    * callback for this Activity. Called when an Activity which was started by
    * this.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode) sets its result and calls finish()
    */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        String foo = "foo";
        switch (requestCode) {
            case Constants.REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE:
                switch (resultCode) {
                    case RESULT_FIRST_USER:
                        Toast.makeText(this, data.getStringExtra(Config.SCAN_RESULT_TEXT), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case RESULT_CANCELED:
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                break;

            default:
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                break;
        }
    }
}


public class CaptureActivity extends Activity implements ActivityCallback, SurfaceHolder.Callback, PreviewCallback {

    private Preview mPreview;
    private Camera mCam;
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Size size;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.capture);

        mPreview = (Preview)findViewById(R.id.capture_preview); 
    }

    @Override
    public void onValidDecodeResult(Result rawResult, Bitmap barcode) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        if (rawResult != null && barcode != null) {
            intent.putExtra(Config.SCAN_RESULT_TEXT, rawResult.getText());
            intent.putExtra(Config.SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT, rawResult.getBarcodeFormat().getName());
            intent.putExtra(Config.SCAN_RESULT_BMP, barcode);
        } else {
            intent.putExtra(Config.SCAN_RESULT_TEXT, "foo");
            intent.putExtra(Config.SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT, "bar");
            intent.putExtra(Config.SCAN_RESULT_BMP, "barcode");
        }
        mPreview = null;
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_FIRST_USER, intent);
        finish();   
    }

    @Override
    public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        MultiFormatReader reader = new MultiFormatReader();     
        PlanarYUVLuminanceSource source = new PlanarYUVLuminanceSource(data, size.width, size.height, 160, 60, 480, 360);
        GlobalHistogramBinarizer binarizer = new GlobalHistogramBinarizer(source);
        BinaryBitmap bb = new BinaryBitmap(binarizer);
        Result result = null;
        try {
            result = reader.decode(bb);
        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            //do NOTHING cause e == null
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            reader.reset();
        }
        if (result != null) {
            mCam.stopPreview();
            releaseCameraResources();
            onValidDecodeResult(result, source.renderCroppedGreyscaleBitmap());
        } else {
            camera.setOneShotPreviewCallback(this);
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            mCam = Camera.open();
            mCam.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            releaseCameraResources();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }

    private void releaseCameraResources() {
        mCam.release();
        mCam = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
        int height) {
        //begin Preview
        Camera.Parameters parameters = mCam.getParameters();

        List<Size> sizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

        size = getOptimalPreviewSize(sizes, width, height);
        parameters.setPreviewSize(size.width, size.height);

        mCam.setParameters(parameters);
        mCam.startPreview();
        mCam.setOneShotPreviewCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        if (mCam != null) {
            mCam.stopPreview();
            releaseCameraResources();
        }   
    }

    private Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Size> sizes, int width, int height) {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.05;
        double targetRatio = (double) width / height;

        if (sizes == null) return null; 
            Size optimalSize = null;
            double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

            int targetHeight = height;

            for (Size size: sizes) {
                double ratio = (double) size.width / size.height;
                if(Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }               
            }

            if (optimalSize == null) {
                //cannot find matching aspect-ratio
                minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
                for (Size size : sizes) {
                    if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                        optimalSize = size;
                        minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }
        return optimalSize;
    }
}
```

Comment: outline the code and click the code button on the toolbar.

Comment: Did you tried to put breakpoint in onValidDecodeResult function? Maybe it is never entered and thus there is no result in parent activity?

Comment: Yes, I had put a breakpoint in onValidDecodeResult. It is triggered as soon the result in onPreviewFrame is NOT null. The data it gets is what I suspect.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I solved the problem myself now.

After giving up to get `onActivityResult` triggering, I decided to 'hack' Androids encapsulating by passing a static reference from MainActivity to CaptureActivity, even if I know that this isn't a good idea.

After the `finish()` call, MAGICALLY `onActivityResult` gets triggered with `Context.RESULT_CANCELLED`... as expected because I don't call `setResult` anymore.

Getting `onActivityResult` triggered I investigated why it is working now. I found out, that it has something to do with the bitmap, passed to an Intent. If I put a `Parcellable` Bitmap into my resultIntent `onActivityResult` never gets fired.

So removing following line in the code above will work:

```
intent.putExtra(Config.SCAN_RESULT_BMP, barcode);
```

Thats ok for me, because I don't needed the BitMap really in this other Activity. It was more a 'feature' than a need.

If some of you guys want to pass big Data into an `Intent` like a `Bitmap`, think about storing it somewhere on SD, passing the path in the Intent, while reading this `Bitmap` from SD in ParentActivity ([How to take a photo by Intent](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html)).

As stated [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/TransactionTooLargeException.html), the Limit of a `Parcelable` is 1MB, thus everything bigger passed to an `Intent` will cause an **internal** `TransactionTooLargeException` and will silently fail

Comment: another case where the cause might be hard to spot: When having such embed scheme TabActivity -> ActivityGroup ->Activity and the last embedded entities (Activity) get shown by making use of the Window.getDecorView() method - do not call startActivityForResult() from within the last embedded entity, but from one step higher, so from ActivityGroup. Also wait for the result in that same ActivityGroup instance.

Comment: It solved my problem. But, could you please make an explanation why it doesn't work when you do putExtra()?

Comment: @AndrewDashin No, i could not really. I can only assume, that my bitmap was too large to be parceled.

Comment: Ran into the same problem... Who would have known that trying to return parcelable bitmap would make onActivityResult() to never get called??? -__-

Btw, thanks a lot for this post.. Save me lots of time!

Answer (score 56):

Make sure the number parameter (`requestCode`) passed to `startActivityForResult(...)` is >=0

Comment: Oh my God! I don't even think about it! But was better to say: "Make sure the passed **`requestCode`** is ...". It is more clear.

Answer (score 42):

Had the same problem. check your manifest and make sure you are NOT using single instance:

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

Comment: For me it was 
`android:noHistory="true"` 
that I deleted.

Comment: +1 but,what if you are using SearchView and you have to set launchmode to SingleInstante; is there any way to stop opening new activity for searchView ??

Comment: Weird behaviour. Thanks for the tip. Worked for me since the onactivityResult stop being called after adding that on the activity.

Comment: ...or SingleTask. On the caller activity.

Answer (score 30):

Deleting `android:noHistory="true"` from the activity I was having problem with solved the issue for me.

Comment: You rock bruh ! Great find. Thanks

Comment: @ralphgabb You bet!

Comment: this saved my day

Answer (score 7):

In my case, it was not triggered since I had added flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` while creating intent for `startActivityForResult`. Removing it solved my issue.

Answer (score 5):

Another variant on this one.  From a DialogFragment, you can `startActivityForResult`.  But if your Intent is started from the associated Activity, you must include `getActivity()` before `startActivityForResult`.  See below (last line):

```
Activity activeOne=FileDialogWindow.this.getActivity();
Intent intent = new Intent(activeOne,FolderSelectionActivity.class);
String message = "foobar";
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent,1);
```

Comment: Please use markup (backticks) to format the `code-words` in your text.

Comment: Thank you sooo much for this answer - saved my day/night!

Comment: I had started the activity for result from another thread. So I had to implement `runOnUIThread()`

Answer (score 1):

It might just be the case that your previous activity doesn't finish? Trying debugging using Log.d and view logcat to see whether the call stack actually reaches the finish() statement in your CaptureActivity class.

Comment: how can the CaptureActivity NOT be finish if I call this.finish() in CaptureActivity. If I put a breakpoint to the finish() call it is triggered in Activity.class from Android. I put a Log to onDestroy to see if it gets called and it gets called. any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

in my case, the scan request code must be ***IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE***,

that is

`startActivityForResult(intent, IntentIntegrator.REQUEST_CODE)`.

Hope can help you.