# Android: Not able to call onActivityResult() method after capturing photo by camera

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent

In my application when I call camera intent by:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

it not call `onActivityResult()` method.

Problem in my application is that some time it calls this method, but some time after capturing photo it again come to photo capture screen.

Before capturing photo I am saving a lot of data in `onSaveInstanceState()` after that I am collecting this data by `onRestoreInstanceState()`.

Here I don't know why some time `onActivityResult()` method calls but some time this method does not call after entering into the photo capture mode.

onActivityResult() code:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    String fileName = null;
    try {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
            roughBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            final ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            final String[] p1 = new String[] {
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
                    MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN };
            Cursor c1 = cr.query(
                MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, p1, null,
                        null, p1[1] + " DESC");
                if (c1.moveToFirst()) {
                    String uristringpic = "content://media/external/images/media/"
                            + c1.getInt(0);
                    newuri = Uri.parse(uristringpic);
                    // Log.i("TAG", "newuri "+newuri);
                    snapName = getRealPathFromURI(newuri);
                    Uri u = Uri.parse(snapName);

                    File f = new File("" + u);
                    fileName = f.getName();
                }
                c1.close();

                  setImageParameter();

            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {

        }
        System.out.println("*** End of onActivityResult() ***");
    }

public void setImageParameter() {
    // decode full image
    roughBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(snapName);
    // calc exact destination size
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    RectF inRect = new RectF(0, 0, roughBitmap.getWidth(),
            roughBitmap.getHeight());
    // RectF outRect = new RectF(0, 0, dstWidth, dstHeight);
    RectF outRect = new RectF(0, 0, 640, 480);
    matrix.setRectToRect(inRect, outRect, Matrix.ScaleToFit.CENTER);
    float[] values = new float[9];
    matrix.getValues(values);
    // resize bitmap
    resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(roughBitmap,
            (int) (roughBitmap.getWidth() * values[0]),
            (int) (roughBitmap.getHeight() * values[4]), true);

    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    paint.setTextSize(16);
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resizedBitmap);

    canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(lat), resizedBitmap.getWidth() - 290, resizedBitmap.getHeight() - 50, paint);
    canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(lng), resizedBitmap.getWidth() - 140, resizedBitmap.getHeight() - 50, paint);
    if (!editTextRoadName.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        canvas.drawText(editTextRoadName.getText().toString(), resizedBitmap.getWidth() - 290, resizedBitmap.getHeight() - 30, paint);
    }
    canvas.drawText(new DateClass().getSysDateTimeForPhoto(), resizedBitmap.getWidth() - 290, resizedBitmap.getHeight() - 10, paint);



    if (nFinalOrientation == 1) {
        matrix.postRotate(90);
    } else {
        matrix.postRotate(0);
    }


    rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(resizedBitmap,
            (int) (resizedBitmap.getWidth() * values[0]),
            (int) (resizedBitmap.getHeight() * values[4]), true);

    if (booleanPhotoFlag) {
        booleanPhotoFlag = false;
        photoBitmap = rotatedBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        imageViewPhoto.setImageBitmap(photoBitmap);

    } else {
        landmarkBitmap = rotatedBitmap.copy(rotatedBitmap.getConfig(), rotatedBitmap.isMutable() ? true : false);
        imageViewLocationPhoto.setImageBitmap(landmarkBitmap);
    }

}
```

Comment: I have answered this question before
take a look:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/30266776/1531683

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have created a [Camera Library Project](https://github.com/girishnair12345/Girish-Camera-Library-Project) you can use this to take picture. I would suggest you to use this library to take picture

***EDIT 2:***

Look try placing a log between `protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` and `super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` to see if even that method is being called or not, If its called then check the value that is returned. **AND** The onActivityResult is not called by your activity but by the calling activity in this case the `intent` of `MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` so your onActivityResult has to be called by the `setResult()` of the calling activity. But I hope your not trying to pass the bitmap via intent [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019711/android-onactivityresult-not-called-triggered)

Comment: Links are not good answer; neither libraries; especially for a less complex task

Comment: @MoJo The link is a project that i have created as library for camera handling. Why paste the code here when i can show a proper path, First at-least consider reading it or visiting the link before down voting

Comment: i know you've given a library; but do you think that a library is required to perform the action tat vikash wanted? world is already complex dont make it even more complex; If you're able to write a library, then you should be able to pick the code for him to perform that task; thats what he wants too

Comment: @MoJoThe MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE doesnt always work, I had once used and was getting similar result like him and some times it doesnt work only. That is why i had to create a such a library. Libraries are used to make things simple not complex.

Comment: adding a library makes your project bulky; your prob with action image capture is due to handset default cam app's customization; you can avoid it if you think sharp; This conversation is done

Comment: Thank you all....
but you guys not specify what is the problem. Why some time onActivityResult() method is called some times it not called.

Comment: @VinitVikash : I need to see your OnActivityResult method to say exactly where ur problem is

Comment: @MoJo I edited my question I mention full code in onActivityResult() method.

Comment: @Vinit: Please check the EDIT 2 of my answer

Answer (score 1):

Check whether permissions are set in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is for getting bigger bigmap where you have to store the image file in the disk first.

Answer (score 1):

I was using `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` in my activity in manifest.xml. Removed it and it started working again. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating an intent like this

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                        android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 0);
```

and an `onActivityResult` like this

```
public void onActivityResult(int intRequestCode, int intResultCode,
            Intent objresult) {
        if (intResultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (intRequestCode == 0) {
            try {
                Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) objresult.getExtras().get("data");
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
                strAttachmentCoded = new String(byteArray);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Picture not stored. Please try again",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

:)

Comment: are u testing on a device or emulator?

Comment: In my application I am capturing two photo. When the first photo is capture then I resize it putting name on photo and then store into the bitmap same thing I am doing for second photo. So I think because of internal memory the problem occur

Comment: i think you should capture a picture, get it back to your app using the onactivityresult i posted, then again go back from here with a different request id comeback and do the processing for both;

Answer (score 0):

```
I faced same problem , once check have you put any tag related to History ?
Do not put android:noHistory="true" tag in manifest 
if you use android:noHistory="true" in your activity inside manifest , it will
remove from stack after on stop .
```

Note : if you are using tab activity then also you should not use android:noHistory="true"
    or else simply put android:noHistory="false" in activity inside manifest .